# Eclipse: The selection did not contain any resources that may run on a server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am currently pursuing a course on Advanced Java. While learning to create JSP Files, I am using Tomcat server and Eclipse IDE. The two connected perfectly well. However, while running the file 'helloworld.jsp' the option 'Run on Server' is available only for one time. After which the option disappears and also the error is detected "The selection did not contain any resources that may run on a server".

How should I proceed with this? I even have tried with several troubleshooting like addition and deletion of the server. But nothing seems to work well.

Comment: check dynamic web module in the project facets

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: show your directory structure,did you have jsp under WEB-INF??

Answer (score 1):

Did you add server from Window >> Show View >> Server >> Servers?
I think it maybe cause for appearing only once "Run on Server".